# CSV Parsing and Insert to Database - Null Values and Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, csv, sqlite

Im using the following code to parse a CSV and insert the values into a table

```
void readcsv()
{
    FILE* stream = fopen("input.csv", "r");

    char line[1024];
    while (fgets(line, 1024, stream))
    {
        char* tmp = strdup(line);


    char a1[20]= "";
    char b1[20]= "";
    char c1[20]= "";
    char d1[20]= "";
    char e1[20]= "";
    char f1[20]= ""; 
    strcat(a1, getcsvfield(tmp, 1));
    strcat(b1, getcsvfield(tmp, 2));
    strcat(c1, getcsvfield(tmp, 3));
    strcat(d1, getcsvfield(tmp, 4));
    strcat(e1, getcsvfield(tmp, 5));
    strcat(f1, getcsvfield(tmp, 6));
    strcat(a1, '\0');
    strcat(b1, '\0');
    strcat(c1, '\0');
    strcat(d1, '\0');
    strcat(e1, '\0');
    strcat(f1, '\0');

        // printf("Field 1 would be %s\n", a1);
        // printf("Field 2 would be %s\n", getcsvfield(tmp, 2));
        // printf("Field 2 would be %s\n", getcsvfield(tmp, 3));
        // printf("Field 2 would be %s\n", getcsvfield(tmp, 4));
        // printf("Field 2 would be %s\n", getcsvfield(tmp, 5));
        // printf("Field 2 would be %s\n", getcsvfield(tmp, 6));
  //---   //   execute("INSERT INTO sdata(sid,name,area,type,stbamount,pkgamount) VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s');",a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1);
        // NOTE strtok clobbers tmp
        free(tmp);
    }
}
//Used for parsing CSV
const char* getcsvfield(char* line, int num)
{
    char buffer[1024]= {0};
    strcpy(buffer, line);

    const char* tok;
    for (tok = strtok(buffer, ";");
            tok && *tok;
            tok = strtok(NULL, ";\n"))
    {
        if (!--num)
            return tok;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

This is the CSV

```
me;val1;val2;val3;val4;val5;
me;val1;val2;val3;val4;val5;
```

ERROR:
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

UPDATE:
***database.c***

```
#include "../include/header.h"
int Open_Database()
{
    int rc=0;

    rc = Initialize_db();
    if(rc == 0)
    {
        printf("\nFailed to initialize db");
        return FAILED;
    }
    printf("\n Database initialization success");

    rc = open_sqlite("/mnt/jffs2/db2.db");
    if(rc == 0)
    {
        printf("\n Failed to open db");
        return FAILED;
    }
    else

        printf("Database already exists\n");
        printf("\n database opened\n");

    return SUCCESS;
}

int Initialize_db()
{
    char *database = "/mnt/jffs2/db2.db";
    int rc=0, i=0;
    struct stat buf;

    i = stat(database, &buf );
    if((i<0) || (buf.st_size == 0))
    {
        printf("Initializing database...\n");
        lk_dispclr();
        lk_disptext(2,0,(unsigned char *)"  Initializing DB...",0);

        rc = open_sqlite(database);
        if(rc == 0)
        {
            printf("Create database failure!\n");
            lk_dispclr();
            //DispText(2,0,"   Failed to Create",0);
            //DispText(4,4,"       Database",0);
            lk_getkey();
            return FAILED;
        }
        else
        {
            rc = execute("CREATE TABLE if not exists sdata(sid VARCHAR(10),name VARCHAR(20),area VARCHAR(10),type VARCHAR(10),stbamount VARCHAR(10),pkgamount VARCHAR(10))");
            if(rc==0)
            {
                return error_handler(rc);
            }

            else
            {
                printf("\n Master table created\n");
            }
                         rc = execute("CREATE TABLE if not exists tdata(sid VARCHAR(10),stbamount VARCHAR(10),pkgamount VARCHAR(10))");
            if(rc==0)
            {
                return error_handler(rc);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\n Transaction table created\n");
            }

         }
     close_sqlite();
     }
    else
    {
        printf("database already existed\n");

        rc=1;
    }
    return rc;
}


int error_handler(int rc)
{
    if(rc == 0)
    {
        printf("\n SQL Error while initializing!!!\n");
        /*lk_dispclr();
        DispText(2,0,"    SQL ERROR",0);
        lk_getkey();
        */
        return FAILED;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("SQL Successfull\n");
        /*lk_dispclr();
        DispText(2,0,"  SQL Successfull",0);
        lk_getkey();*/
    }
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
***e_sqlite.c***

```
#include "../include/sqlite3.h"
#include "../include/header.h"

#define ELEMENT_NUM(_array) ( sizeof(_array)/sizeof(_array[0]) )

sqlite3 *db_conn;
int ret = 0;
char OPEN_FLAG = 0;

int open_sqlite(char *db_name)
{
    if(OPEN_FLAG == 0)
    {
        if(sqlite3_open(db_name, &db_conn) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            OPEN_FLAG = 1;
            printf("\nOPEN_FALG = %d\n",OPEN_FLAG);
            printf("database opened\n");
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("database opening failed\n");
                return 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\ndatabase already opened\n");
        return 1;
    }
    return 1;
}

int close_sqlite()
{
    if(OPEN_FLAG == 1)
    {
        if(sqlite3_close(db_conn) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            printf("database closed\n");
            OPEN_FLAG = 0;
            printf("OPEN_FLAG = %d\n",OPEN_FLAG);
                return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("database closing failed\n");
                return 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("database not yet opened\n");
        return 1;
    }
}

//only type s and d are allowed as arguments
int execute(const char* fmt, ...)
{
    char *err_messg;
    int ret=0, result = 0;

    char sql_string[2000]="";//this honestly needs to be more elegant; will do for now
    //char sql_string[1024]="";//this honestly needs to be more elegant; will do for now
    va_list args;   
    va_start(args, fmt);

    SQLITE = 1;

    memset(sql_string,0,sizeof(sql_string));

    sql_string[0] = '\0';
    ret = vsprintf(sql_string, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);   
    err_printf(sql_string);//

    if(!ret)
        result = 0;
    else
        result = 1;
    if(result != -1)
    {
        if(sqlite3_exec(db_conn, sql_string, NULL, 0, &err_messg) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            result = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(stdout,"SQL error: %s\n", err_messg);
            result = 0;
        }
    }

    SQLITE = 0;
    return result;
}

//you must open_sqlite first before using execute_file
int execute_file(char *filename)
{
    char *err_messg;
    FILE *read_fd = (FILE *) 0;
    char sql_string[1024];

    ret = 0;

    read_fd = fopen (filename, "r");//open file for read    
    if (read_fd != NULL)
    {
        rewind(read_fd);
        while(!feof (read_fd))
        {
            m_fgets(sql_string, 1024, read_fd);

            //ie if string is not empty, then execute - ha no more newline errors!
            if(strcmp(sql_string, "") != 0)
            {
                //err_printf("SQL_STRING: %s\n", sql_string);   

                if(sqlite3_exec(db_conn, sql_string, NULL, 0, &err_messg) == SQLITE_OK)
                {
                    ret = 1;
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    fprintf(stdout,"SQL error: %s\n", err_messg);
                    ret = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(read_fd);    
        return ret;
}

char *m_fgets(char *line, int n, FILE *fd)
{
    int c = 0;
    char *cstring;

    cstring = line;
    while(--n>0 && ( c = getc(fd) ) != EOF)
    {
        if (c == '\n')
            break;

        *cstring++ = c;
    }
    *cstring++ = '\0';

    if (c == EOF && cstring == line)//ie nothing in file!
        line = NULL;

    if (c == EOF)
        line = NULL;

    return line;
}

resultset get_result(const char* fmt, ...)
{
    int success = 0;
    int nrow=0, ncol=0, i=0, j=0, count=0;
    char *err_messg;
    char **result;
    char ***recordset;
    resultset resultset_table;

    char sql_string[1500];//this honestly needs to be more elegant; will do for now
    va_list args;   
    va_start(args, fmt);
    sql_string[0] = '\0';
    ret = vsprintf(sql_string, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);   
    fprintf(stdout,"\n%s\n", sql_string);

    SQLITE = 1;

    //initialize resultset_table;
    resultset_table.rows = 0;
    resultset_table.cols = 0;
    resultset_table.recordset = NULL;

    ret = sqlite3_get_table(
                    db_conn,              
                    sql_string,
                    &result,
                    &nrow,
                    &ncol,
                    &err_messg
                );

    fprintf(stdout,"nrow=%d ncol=%d\n",nrow,ncol);

    recordset = (char ***)malloc(nrow * sizeof(char **));
    for(count=ncol; count<((nrow + 1)*ncol); count++)
    {
        recordset[i] = (char **)malloc(ncol * sizeof(char *));
        for(j=0; j<ncol; j++)
        {
            err_printf("%s ",result[count]);//
            recordset[i][j] = (char *) malloc( (strlen(result[count]) + 1) );
            strcpy(recordset[i][j], result[count]);

            if(j != (ncol - 1))
                count++;
        }
        i++;
        err_printf("\n");//
    }
    sqlite3_free_table(result);

    if( ret != SQLITE_OK )
    {
        fprintf(stdout,"SQL error: %s\n", err_messg);
        success = 0; 
        }

    else
    {
        resultset_table.rows = nrow;
        resultset_table.cols = ncol;
        resultset_table.recordset = recordset;
        success = 1;
    }

    SQLITE = 0;
    return resultset_table;
}

//will free all allocd memory ie only recordset memory (since only that allocd)
void free_result(resultset resultset_table)
{
    int i=0,j=0;

    if(resultset_table.recordset != NULL)
        {
                for(i=0;i<resultset_table.rows;i++)
                {
                        for(j=0;j<resultset_table.cols;j++)
                        {
                                free(resultset_table.recordset[i][j]);
                        }
                        free(resultset_table.recordset[i]);
                }
                free(resultset_table.recordset);
        }
}

//if DEBUG is on then print message to stderr using fprintf function
/*int err_printf(const char *fmt, ...)
{
        int i;

        va_list ap;
        va_start(ap, fmt);
        i = vfprintf(stderr, fmt, ap);
        va_end(ap);

        return i;
}*/
//returns the row index in the resultset that was selected
//column is the column of the resultset that you want to display
int err_printf(const char *fmt, ...)
{
        int i;

//        #ifdef DEBUG
                va_list ap;
                va_start(ap, fmt);
                i = vfprintf(stderr, fmt, ap);
                va_end(ap);
 //       #endif

        return i;
}
```

Update:

Fix for Null Values:

Comment: Just compile your code with debug flags ( -g3 in case of gcc or clang ) and then run in debugger e.g. gdb ./a.out. After segmentation fault you can see backtrace with bt command of gdb. You can also analyse existing core dump with gdb.

Comment: @pikkewyn Please see the update..

Comment: It would be great if you could provide complete example of problematic code, I'm trying to reproduce this error but with no luck.

Comment: @pikkewyn Thanks... this code is for a machine... so the full code has API Calls.. its very long....Do you want me to provide the whole project?

Comment: @user3121023 Thanks.. what should i do to fix this? Please suggest.

Comment: @user3121023 Please see the 2nd update..now the values are not null.. but i get segmentation fault.

Comment: @user3121023 Im getting the print from the execute method ... the query string is correct.

Comment: @user3121023 Please see the latest update.

Comment: @pikkewyn Please see the update.

Comment: @user3121023 Even if i remove all strcat(a1, '\0');..... the code does not work

Comment: @user3121023 But when printing the values in a1,b1 etc the output is correct its only when inserting it into the db.. the problem comes up.

Comment: You probably should create new question with prepared complete example of problematic code. Even if it's big project try to extract only necessary bits and put them together to reproduce problem and ask for help. Or you can contact me on studies[dot]tutor[at]gmail[dot]com in case of further problems.

Comment: @pikkewyn okay... will try

Comment: regarding this line: `return tok;`,  this is returning a pointer into a char array that is located on the stack of the `getcsvfield()`   when that function exits, the char array goes `out of scope` so the caller will receive a pointer to trash.  suggest either calling `malloc()` for the char array or placing the char array in the file global space (prefix with the `static` modifier)

Comment: in function: `readcsv()` suggest replacing the calls to `strcat()` with calls to `strncat( ..., getcsvfield(tmp, 1), 19);` so as to avoid any possibility of overflowing the buffers `a1` ... `f1`.

Comment: the function: `strdup()` can fail, so should check that `tmp` is not NULL before using that variable

Comment: no need in the `readcsv()` function to be using `strcat()` to append a NUL byte,  the call to `strtok()` already handled that detail.

Comment: when calling `strcat()` the 'source' parameter (second parameter) must not be NULL, other wise will try to get input from address 0 which will result in undefined behaviour and a seg fault event.

Comment: given that there is no guarantee that each line in the `input.csv` file is actually 1023 bytes or less, it might be much better to use `getline()`,  Then no need to call strdup(), etc.

Comment: in the commented out calls to `printf()`, all the arrays are already filled in, so no need (and probably not a good idea) to be calling `getcsvfield()` again.

Comment: @user3629249 I got this to work... the issue was that i forgot to open the database before calling this method.Thanks a lot for your suggestions :)